# Simple Journey will not send E-Mail

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

**Steps I performed:**

1. Created a first Data Extension (DE) with the following fields:

   - SubscriptionKey >> primary key and required
   - Email >> not required
   - Mobile >> not required
   - Firstname >> not required
   - Lastname >> not required

     1.1 This DE is set to sendable and is used as root

     1.2 I have imported the Records
2. Populated "All Subscribers" with the SubscriptionKeys that appear in the first DE. Hence SubscriberKey from AllSubscribers matches the PrimaryKey from the first DE
3. Created a second Data Extension with the following fields:

   - SubscriptionKey >> NOT primary key but required
   - Email >> NOT primary key but required

     3.1. This DE is set to sendable and is used/marked as root

     3.2. I have imported the Records
4. Created a POPULATION and linked Contacts to the first Data Extension via ContactKey and SubscriptionKey (1:1 relation)
5. Created an ATTRIBUTE GROUP and linked Contacts to the second Data Extension via SubscriptionKey and ContactKey (1:1 relation)
6. Order of Emails in Contact Builder - I have created a new Email and adjusted the order.
7. Created my Email and Content using Content Builder
8. Created a super simple Journey

   - Target Group >> Email Studio Audience >> Selected DE was the Second Data Extension
   - no further contact filters what so ever
   - Re-Entry after finishing the Journey
   - Testing showed no errors

**My Result:**

- my contacts get processed
- they met the criteria
- contacts are accepted
- no email has been received

**What I have tried so far:**

- create an SQL Automation
- do it w/o the second DE

Comment: If you open Email app > Tracking [menu] > Sends > Journey Builder Sends > Journey Name > Version, do you see the emails that have been sent?

Comment: Hi Eliot, thanks for helping me out. Unfortunately there is nothing there. Although once the E-Mail has been sent. The following time the send always failed.